# Bower install jquery-ui missing gruntfile

Tags: jquery-ui, gruntjs, bower

When I do a bower install jquery-ui --save , bower_modules/jquery-ui is created.

This repo does not contain  the Gruntfile.js

Does bower install delete files from the repo?
Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery-ui used by this bower package points to https://github.com/components/jqueryui and not to https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui

This repo only contains the precompiled files from jquery-ui.